# Json Array data not getting into the ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, android-volley

I get a response from JSON Array using Volley. I get the strings which I need. 
I want to put those strings in an ArrayList so as to put the data in the recyclerview adapter. But, that is not happening.

Here is the Json Request:

```
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);

    RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
    String url ="http://www.drunkenwords.in/web.php";

    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray;
                    ArrayList<Model> resp = new ArrayList<>();
                    try {
                        jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("info");
                        String x= response.getString("status");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,x,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){


                            resp.add(new Model(jsonArray.getString(i)));
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,resp.get(i).getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                        mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(resp);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("y", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    queue.add(req);

    mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(ar);

    mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
    String url ="http://www.drunkenwords.in/web.php";

    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray;
                    ArrayList<Model> resp = new ArrayList<>();
                    try {
                        jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("info");
                        String x= response.getString("status");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,x,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){


                            resp.add(new Model(jsonArray.getString(i)));
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,resp.get(i).getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                        mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(resp);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("y", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    queue.add(req);

    mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(ar);

    mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This

```
try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("info");
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String x= jobj.getString("status");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,x,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    resp.add(new Model(jsonArray.getString(i)));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,resp.get(i).getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("exception", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());                   
            }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);

RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
String url ="http://www.drunkenwords.in/web.php";

JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                JSONArray jsonArray;
                ArrayList<Model> resp = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("info");
                    String x= response.getString("status");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,x,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){


                        resp.add(new Model(jsonArray.getString(i)));
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,resp.get(i).getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(resp);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("y", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
});

queue.add(req);

mRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

mRecyclerViewAdapter.setItems(ar);
```